# Python regex: re.search() does not find string

Tags: python, regex, string, search, no-match

I have trouble using the re.search() method. I am trying to extract an image link from following string explicit:

`div class="beitragstext">\n\t\t\t\t<p>Es gibt derzeit keine GrÃ¼nde mehr NICHT auf 1.1.3 zu springen!</p>\n<p><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/factoryjoe/372948722/"><img src="https://www.iphoneblog.de/wp-content/uploads/2008/02/372948722-6ec4028a80.jpg" alt="372948722_6ec4028a80.jpg" border="0" width="430" height="466" /></a></p>\n<p>Photo: <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/factoryjoe">factoryjoe</a>`

I want to substract the URL of the first image, and the URL only.

This is my code:
`imageURLObject = re.search(r'http(?!.*http).*?\.(jpg|png|JPG|PNG)', match)`

The result should be `https://www.iphoneblog.de/wp-content/uploads/2008/02/372948722-6ec4028a80.jpg`

Instead, the method return is None. 
But if use this regex `re.search(r'http.*?\.(jpg|png|JPG|PNG)', match)`, without the `*(?!.*http)*, the first *http* hit will match until *.(jpg|png|JPG|PNG)* and this would be the return:

`http://www.flickr.com/photos/factoryjoe/372948722/"><img src="https://www.iphoneblog.de/wp-content/uploads/2008/02/372948722-6ec4028a80.jpg`

Can someone help me please ? :-)

Comment: Will the image link always come after 'src='?

Comment: Yes it does, I didn't notice before. I added it to my regex and now it works. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Beautiful soup for HTML parsing..

https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="beitragstext">\n\t\t\t\t<p>Es gibt derzeit keine GrÃ¼nde mehr NICHT auf 1.1.3 zu springen!</p>\n<p><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/factoryjoe/372948722/"><img src="https://www.iphoneblog.de/wp-content/uploads/2008/02/372948722-6ec4028a80.jpg" alt="372948722_6ec4028a80.jpg" border="0" width="430" height="466" /></a></p>\n<p>Photo: <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/factoryjoe">factoryjoe</a>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
links = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'beitragstext'})

for i in links:
    print(i.find('img')['src'])

>>> https://www.iphoneblog.de/wp-content/uploads/2008/02/372948722-6ec4028a80.jpg
```

Comment: You  can also use requests to grab the html direct from a url..read the docs.. very straightforward!